# How to install HHVM on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: hhvm

I've followed the instructions in the [Hack Documentation for 15.10](https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/installation/linux#ubuntu-15.10-wily-werewolf) but that is not working for me --

dddddd@~$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
[sudo] password for dddddd: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
software-properties-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

dddddd@~$ sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0x5a16e7281be7a449
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.jQ1p1f6X1y --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0x5a16e7281be7a449
gpg: requesting key 1BE7A449 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 1BE7A449: public key "Paul Tarjan " imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)

dddddd@~$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main'
dddddd@~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security InRelease
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release Release.gpg
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main amd64 Packages 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Err http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release/-sc) amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Err http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release/-sc) i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Err http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release/-sc) Translation-en_US
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release/-sc) Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/-sc)/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/-sc)/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

dddddd@~$ sudo apt-get install hhvm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package hhvm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'hhvm' has no installation candidate

---

I've followed the instructions in the [Hack Documentation for 15.04](http://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/installation/linux#ubuntu-15.04-vivid) but that is not working for me --

dddddd@x64:~$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
[sudo] password for dddddd: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
software-properties-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

dddddd@x64:~$ sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0x5a16e7281be7a449
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.UWfZBZeE4j --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0x5a16e7281be7a449
gpg: requesting key 1BE7A449 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 1BE7A449: "Paul Tarjan " not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1

dddddd@x64:~$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main'

dddddd@x64:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily InRelease
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security InRelease [64.4 kB]
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release Release.gpg
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates InRelease [64.4 kB]
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Sources
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Sources [18.9 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Sources
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Sources [2,854 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main amd64 Packages
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Sources [5,896 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted amd64 Packages
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Sources [1,922 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe amd64 Packages
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main amd64 Packages [58.0 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main i386 Packages
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted amd64 Packages [10.9 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted i386 Packages
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe amd64 Packages [28.9 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe i386 Packages
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [5,859 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main i386 Packages [56.9 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Translation-en
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted i386 Packages [10.8 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Translation-en
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe i386 Packages [28.9 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Translation-en
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse i386 Packages [6,052 B]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Translation-en
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Sources [31.7 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Translation-en
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Sources [3,741 B]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Translation-en
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Sources [7,766 B]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Translation-en
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Sources [1,922 B]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main amd64 Packages [89.0 kB] 
Err http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release/-sc) amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release/-sc) i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release/-sc) Translation-en_US
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [13.3 kB]
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release/-sc) Translation-en
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe amd64 Packages [38.0 kB]
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com $(lsb_release/main Translation-en
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [5,859 B]
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main i386 Packages [87.6 kB]
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted i386 Packages [13.4 kB]
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe i386 Packages [38.0 kB]
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [6,052 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Translation-en
Fetched 701 kB in 8s (81.8 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/-sc)/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/-sc)/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

dddddd@x64:~$ sudo apt-get install hhvm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package hhvm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'hhvm' has no installation candidate

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Those directions don't work since they're the wrong distro. Binary packages are intimately tied to the distro they're built on, and so trying to cross this over until we provide packages just isn't going to work. We [don't yet provide binaries for 15.10 but have an open issue about it](https://github.com/hhvm/packaging/issues/136), and I hope we can start doing so this week.

However, following another distro's instructions when building from source might have more luck? You can try to follow [our docs for building from source](http://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/installation/building-from-source); the 15.04 directions there *might* work, and are your best bet. Or you can wait for official support with binaries -- building from source takes several hours and many gigabytes of RAM.

Comment: The docs for building with 15.04 work with 15.10, i installed without problems.

Comment: And nightly binaries for 15.10 are now available, with the 3.11.0 release coming shortly.

Comment: @Guilherme Cardoso -- I listed the instructions I followed, and you can see what happened.

Comment: @Josh Watzman -- I've just tried the "Ubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf" instructions without success.

Comment: Same here unfortunately